# scrollTop to active element in a overflow scroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a specific question about `.scrollTop`. I have a `div` with a specific `height` and a lot of p tags inside:

```
<div id="scroll">
   <p>name1</p>
   <p>name2</p>
   <!-- till name50 -->
</div>
```

depending on the name you click it gets a class `.active`. What I then want to do is scroll the div so, that the name is at the top. So what I get is that I can use scrollTop in an animate function like this:

```
$('#scroll').animate({scrollTop: value });
```

but how can I get the `var value`. I tried it with

```
var value = $('#scroll p').hasClass('active').position().top;
```

But somehow it does not work.

Some help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check `scrollTop()` for the container `#scroll` and add that back to the position() arg.

```
var $scroll = $('#scroll');

$('p').click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $scroll.animate({
        "scrollTop": $this.position().top + $scroll.scrollTop()
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yCEap/1/

To just get the value:

```
var value = $('#scroll').scrollTop();
```

Comment: sorry I might explained myself a bit bad but I want that e.g. in your example I press on the second div, the div scrolls to top of the second element. edit: that the second div is the first top in the div viewport!

Comment: thank you, it works almost in my case. It just jumps to wide in first click, but then everythings fine.